# Python, IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my data:

```
3116,97.208.97.100,13123721655,1806,919831533099,5/3/2016 11:29:22 PM,300000372932,2070200100101,919831533099,D,1,274,5/3/2016 11:29:55 PM,5/3/2016 11:34:04 PM,249,26,0,NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN,0,,2,131286102781596,0,0,4701,2190,60,10950,4701,249,5/3/2016 11:34:04 PM,200,NPS_AS7,97.56.30.7,5/3/2016 11:29:22PM,1,7145,10.236.51.243,0,0,0,3,1,3,765292,776242,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,N,,
```

I want to split the 31 column (`5/3/2016 11:34:04 PM`) into two columns date and time (`fields[30].split(" ")[0]+","+fields[30].split(" ")[1]`) to partition on date wise, but it is showing the error

> index out of range.

This is my code:

```
import os
import datetime as da

cdr_path = "/home/rosa/CDR/cgi/"
dest_path = "/home/rosa/CDR/cgo/"

date = da.datetime.today().strftime("%d%m%Y_%H")
out_file = dest_path+"hadoop_output_"+date+".log"


def preparefile(cdr_path, dest_path):
    with open(out_file,"w") as fo:  #  open output file for writing
        for filename in os.listdir(cdr_path): # list all cdr files for reading
            file_name = cdr_path+filename
            with open(file_name,"r") as fi:
                for line in fi:
                    fields = line.rstrip("\n").split(',')
                    outline = ",".join(fields[:30])
                    outline += ","+fields[30].split(" ")[0]+","+fields[30].split(" ")[1]+","
                    [0]+","+fields[12].split("_")[1]+","
                    outline += ",".join(fields[31:63])+"\n"

                    fo.write(outline)  
            os.remove(file_name)

preparefile(cdr_path, dest_path)
```

I don't know why it is not splitting. Could someone help me to find out?

Comment: can you show the whole error trace? are you sure the error is on the splitting line?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cgnat.py", line 26, in <module>
    preparefile(cdr_path, dest_path)
  File "cgnat.py", line 19, in preparefile
    outline += ","+fields[30].split(" ")[0]+","+fields[30].split(" ")[1]+","
IndexError: list index out of range